# How to change highlight background in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3

Below is the color theme of my sublime text.

[image]

I want to change the background color of the matched texts when I click on some text. As you can see above, there is no background color. I want to change it to black.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Modification based on suggestion from @OdatNurd

Based in @OdatNurd's answer below I applied below modification

[image]

However it did not change background colour of the matched word.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want every find result to be highlighted as if it is the current one? If so, that's not possible out of the box and would require some form of plugin.

The available [color scheme options for find](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html#find) include:

- `highlight` to set the color for the box on matches
- `find_highlight` to set the background color of the current match
- `find_highlight_foreground` to set the foreground color of the current match

The latter two are for marking which of the available matches is the "current" one only; e.g. if you're in the `Replace` panel, that is the match that will be replaced when you press the button.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However it did not change the background colour of the matched words.